# ListAggregatorFactory returns system.collections.generic.list`1[system.object]

Tags: c#, pivot-table, nreco

I've been using the powerful NReco library to create pivot tables.  And using the very convenient HTML wrapper extension to turn those tables into HTML.  When I use the '' I get the following returned into the HTML.

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

The error seems very straight-forward.  The HTML wrapper is probably just calling `ToString()` on the collection object rather then joining the list.  Is there a way to override the HTML wrappers functionality when it comes to formatting this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean pivot table writers (like `PivotTableHtmlWriter`) from NReco.PivotData.Extensions nuget package.

You're right with your suggestion that by default aggregator's value is simply converted to string with `object.ToString()` call. This works good for simple values, however for complex objects (including lists) there are no default representation - this motivates to define your own 'value-formatter' handler and don't rely on any default conventions:

```
pvtHtmlWr.FormatValue = (aggr,measureIdx) => {
  if (aggr.Count==0)
    return String.Empty;

  if (aggr.Value is IList) {
    var ls = (IList)aggr.Value;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<ls.Count; i++) {
      var entryStr = Convert.ToString( ls[i] ); // or apply custom formatting of list entries
      if (entryStr.Length>0) {
        if (sb.Length>0)
          sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(entryStr);
      }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }

  // apply default number format
  return String.Format("{0:0.##}", aggr.Value); 
};
```

More on pivot table values formatting: https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/format-pivot-table.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I was able to implement the list format.  I do have a follow question.  Can you explain this following line of your code.   var entryStr = FF.Format(MeasureFormats[index],ls[i]);  What is "FF" and what is "MeasureFormats"?

Comment: @Juls that was a copy-paste from the real project where measures format may be configured by the end-user (and FF.Format handles this). I've edited a code snippet to remove this project specific thing.